# Sharepoint Designer "Custom action" - 2 actions at once

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a Sharepoint Online site admin and I'm no coder.
I have this requirment which might be odd.
I need to create a list button which will preform **TWO** actions on a selected list item:
**First** - update a field in the selected item
**Second** - go to URL
These 2 actions must be prefomed with **ONE click** only!

Now, I know how to create a button with Sharepoint Designer Custom Actions - but these actions can only carry **ONE** action.

As I mentioned I'm no coder, so I rather not get into any twisty coding and use as many OOB options as posible, but here I'm kind of lost :(